How to Count Connected Components That Form Cycles in an Undirected Graph?
I am working with an undirected graph and need to determine the number of connected components that are also cycles. A cycle is defined as a connected component where each vertex has exactly two edges, and the component contains at least three vertices.
The graph is represented by n vertices and m edges. Each edge connects two distinct vertices, and there are no duplicate edges.
Definitions:

Undirected Graph:

Composed of two sets: one of vertices and the other of edges.
Each edge connects two distinct vertices (( u \neq v )).
There is at most one edge between any pair of vertices.


Connected Component:

A subset of vertices such that any two vertices in this subset are connected by a path, and the subset is not connected to any other vertex outside of it.


Cycle:

A connected component is a cycle if:

It contains at least 3 vertices.
Each vertex is part of exactly 2 edges.
Rearranging its vertices can form a sequence such that the first vertex connects to the second, the second to the third, ..., and the last vertex connects back to the first.





Input:

The first line contains two integers, n (1 ≤ n ≤ 200,000) and m (0 ≤ m ≤ 200,000), representing the number of vertices and edges.
The next m lines each contain two integers, u and v, describing an edge between vertex u and vertex v. There are no duplicate edges, and the graph is undirected.

Output:

A single integer: the number of connected components in the graph that are cycles.

Example:
Input:
17 15
1 8
1 12
5 11
11 9
9 15
15 5
4 13
3 13
4 3
10 16
7 10
16 7
14 3
14 4
17 6

Output:
2

My Attempt:
I implemented the following Python solution, which works for some cases but fails for certain hidden test cases in my university's submission platform. Here’s the code I used:
from collections import defaultdict, deque

def count_cycle_components(n, m, edges):
    # Create an adjacency list for the graph
    graph = defaultdict(list)
    for u, v in edges:
        graph[u].append(v)
        graph[v].append(u)

    # Visited array to track visited nodes
    visited = [False] * (n + 1)

    # Helper function to check if a connected component is a cycle
    def is_cycle_component(node):
        queue = deque([(node, -1)])  # (current node, parent node)
        visited[node] = True
        node_count = 0
        edge_count = 0

        while queue:
            current, parent = queue.popleft()
            node_count += 1
            for neighbor in graph[current]:
                edge_count += 1
                if not visited[neighbor]:
                    visited[neighbor] = True
                    queue.append((neighbor, current))
                elif neighbor != parent:
                    pass  # Neighbor visited and not parent, ignore
        
        # Each edge is counted twice in an undirected graph
        edge_count //= 2

        # Check if the connected component is a cycle
        return node_count >= 3 and edge_count == node_count

    cycle_count = 0

    # Iterate through all nodes to find connected components
    for node in range(1, n + 1):
        if not visited[node]:
            if is_cycle_component(node):
                cycle_count += 1

    return cycle_count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    input = sys.stdin.read
    data = input().splitlines()

    # Read the number of vertices and edges
    n, m = map(int, data[0].split())
    # Read the edges
    edges = [tuple(map(int, line.split())) for line in data[1:]]

    # Output the number of cycle components
    print(count_cycle_components(n, m, edges))

Any idea why does this code might fail for certain test cases? And how can it be corrected or optimized to fix this?

It looks like you are using BFS and not DFS in your traversal, which is the way to go if you are looking for the occurrences of finding a vertex you previously visited.
DFS is perfect for when you want to exhaust one of your directions before backtracking to the next neighbor. BFS is when you want to know something about all the neighbors of a vertex.
[not pointing at a bug since the algorithm is flawed and also - homework]

Here's an alternative method I've tried. I have implemented a DFS approach instead of BFS. And I've created a set for visited which prevents revisting nodes. These changes should improve the algorithm's performance and ensure it passes all test cases. Let me know if it works.
from collections import defaultdict

def count_cycle_components(n, m, edges):
    # Create an adjacency list for the graph
    graph = defaultdict(list)
    for u, v in edges:
        graph[u].append(v)
        graph[v].append(u)

    visited = set()

    def is_cycle_component(node, parent):
        stack = [(node, parent)]
        component_nodes = set()
        edge_count = 0

        while stack:
            current, parent = stack.pop()
            if current in component_nodes:
                continue
            component_nodes.add(current)

            for neighbor in graph[current]:
                edge_count += 1
                if neighbor != parent:
                    stack.append((neighbor, current))

        # Each edge is counted twice in an undirected graph
        edge_count //= 2

        # Check if all nodes in the component have degree 2 and form a cycle
        if len(component_nodes) >= 3 and edge_count == len(component_nodes):
            for node in component_nodes:
                if len(graph[node]) != 2:
                    return False
            return True
        return False

    cycle_count = 0

    # Iterate through all nodes to find connected components
    for node in range(1, n + 1):
        if node not in visited:
            # Mark all nodes in the current component as visited
            component_nodes = set()
            stack = [node]
            while stack:
                current = stack.pop()
                if current not in visited:
                    visited.add(current)
                    component_nodes.add(current)
                    for neighbor in graph[current]:
                        if neighbor not in visited:
                            stack.append(neighbor)

            # Check if the connected component is a cycle
            if is_cycle_component(node, -1):
                cycle_count += 1

    return cycle_count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    input = sys.stdin.read
    data = input().splitlines()

    n, m = map(int, data[0].split())
    edges = [tuple(map(int, line.split())) for line in data[1:]]
    print(count_cycle_components(n, m, edges))


Yes it works.
Now i understand, Thanks!

@אוהדגולדברג hey kindly mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark on the left of my answer, if you found it useful.
